# voting system for rails blog with devise user login before voting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, conditional-statements, voting-system

So I have a blog I am trying to have a simple upvote/downvote feature for the posts. I have devise set up and I made all the associations between the models,  votings, users, and home_blogs.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :liked_home_blogs, through: :votings
end

class HomeBlog < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  has_many :hashtaggings
  has_many :hashtags, through: :hashtaggings
  has_many :votings
  has_many :votants, through: :votings

  def all_hashes=(names)
    self.hashtags = names.split(",").map do |name|
      Hashtag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end

  def all_hashes
    self.hashtags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end
end

class Voting < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :home_blog
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

and the controller looks like this at the moment:

```
class VotingsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

def upvote
    @votings = HomeBlog.find(params[:home_blog_id])
    @votings.votings.build( :upvote => true, :downvote => false, 
:user_id => current_user.id)
    @votings.save!
      redirect_to request.referrer, notice: "Thanks for the 
 vote!"
 end



     def downvote
        @voting = HomeBlog.find(params[:home_blog_id])
        @voting.votings.build( :downvote => true, :upvote => 
    false, :user_id => current_user.id)
        @voting.save!
          redirect_to request.referrer, notice: "Thanks for the 
    vote!"
      end
private 

def voting_params
          params.require(:voting).permit(:upvote, :downvote, 
     :home_blog_id, :user_id)
 end

end
```

Sorry about the crappy copy and paste for the controller. My question is, how do I make a condition for the current_user in devise to limit them to one vote per home_blog post? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would add multicolumn unique index to the join table. Something like...

```
add_index :voting, [:user_id, :home_blog_id], unique: true
```

If im understanding your question correctly you would like there to be only one votings record for a `home_blog` per `current_user`  ( `user_id` )